# How to express the lattice parameter of NaCl in terms of ionic radii?

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry

In the $\ce{NaCl}$ lattice, $\ce{Cl^-}$ takes the FCC configuration, and all the voids at the edge and body center are filled by $\ce{Na^+}.$ So, do we calculate the edge length of unit cell $a$ as

$$a = \frac{4\,R(\ce{Cl-})}{\sqrt2} \tag{1}$$

because of FCC structure, or as

$$a = 2\,R(\ce{Cl-}) + 2\,R(\ce{Na+}) \tag{2}$$

because the edge void is filled?

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is only the chemistry stuff that ought to be put within the braces of the `\ce{}`, the more mathematical stuff should just be written directly within the dollar signs. To write this math, you have to know some MathJax, for which there is a tutorial on this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  I have submitted an edit of your post just to potentially stop it from being closed before you learn some MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the normal FCC, where the corner and face centred atoms are touching each other, we use a*root(2)=4r, but here in the case of NaCl, the positioning is somewhat distorted because of more number of atoms in the same amount of place.
So the Cl atoms are not touching each other rather the Na and Cl atoms, which are on the edge, are touching each other, and hence we use a=2R(Cl)+2R(Na)